# How can I use a system sound as the sound for a UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am writing an alarm app, and I would like to use a system sound such as Tweet as the alarm sound. I understand that the alarm.soundName is of type string, but I have no idea how to apply this sound to the alarm.

```
let alarm: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
alarm.category = "wakeUpAlarms"
alarm.alertAction = "turn off the alarm"
alarm.alertBody = "Time to wake up!"
alarm.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(secondsUntilFire))
// get the system sound (tweet in this case)
let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016
// apply that sound to the alarm
alarm.soundName = systemSoundID     // doesn't work
alarm.userInfo = ["Length": userInfoLength]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(alarm)
```

Comment: The documentation, for one, explicitly states that "System-supplied alert sounds and system-supplied user-interface sound effects are not available to your application".

Comment: Could you show me where that is documented?

Comment: Appears to be a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780609/how-would-i-use-a-system-sound-as-the-sound-for-a-uilocalnotification You should be able to "claim" that question if you log in here with the same credentials that you originally used on Ask Different.

Comment: Yes. It is in the [Media Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW1).

Comment: So does this mean that I absolutely cannot use these sounds my in project?